# Go to current Project Directory in Terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, cmder

I configured Settings > Tools > Terminal according to the [Terminal Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-tools-terminal.html) for cmder and it's working so far. But for some Reason, start directory does not seem to work. I always end up in my userhome when starting a new terminal. How can I fix this?

[image: config]

- Windows 10 Pro 1803, build 17134.137
- ConEmu-Maximus5 171109
- PhpStorm 2018.1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that `%HOME%` is where your `init.bat` leaves you.

Either modify that script, or change your **Shell path** in Terminal settings to 
(please note the double quotes!):

```
"cmd.exe" /K "%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\init.bat & cd /d %cd%"
```

... where:

- `cd /d` means change directory and drive (just in case working directory was on different drive)
- `%cd%` is a variable populated within the terminal with the working directory (**Start directory** from the settings).

Comment: thank you, I got it fixed with `"cmd.exe" /k " "%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\init.bat"" "& cd /d %cd%"`.  For some reason it only works with this exact (and unreasonable) amount of quotes

Answer (score 2):

Looks like either cmd.exe or Cmder is set up so that it's working directory gets changed to %USERPROFILE% once console is opened. Does the issue persist if you change **Shell path** to just `cmd.exe`? If yes, you must have configured the shell to `cd` to a specific folder once it starts (see https://www.winhelponline.com/xp/autoruncmd.htm). Otherwise it should be a Cmder configuration that is responsible for changing a folder to your user home. Check your configs for presence of `:d:%USERPROFILE%` or similar

Comment: My cmder startup task was `cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat"  -new_console:d:%USERPROFILE%`. I removed the :d:%USERPROFILE% but it still didn't work out. Fixed it with the workaround @diginoise posted